# Laravel: Sorting Polymophic Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**HOW TO**

1. > In the Student Controller, how to sort the results by student name?
2. > How to sort the results by student's guardian name?

---

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

- ***taxonomies***

  - id
  - entity_type - *It contains the class name of the owning model.*
  - entity_id - *It contains the ID value of the student.*
- ***students***

  - id
  - name
- ***guardians***

  - id
  - student_id
  - name

---

**CONTROLLER**

- **StudentController.php**

  ```
  public function getStudents()
  {
      return Taxonomy::with([
              'entity', 
              'entity.guardian'
          ])
          ->where('entity_type', 'Student')
          ->get();
  }
  ```

---

**MODEL**

- **Taxonomy.php**

  ```
  public function entity()
  {
      return $this->morphTo();
  }
  ```
- **Student.php**

  ```
  public function taxonomies()
  {
      return $this->morphMany('App\Taxonomy', 'entity');
  }

  public function guardian()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Guardian');
  }
  ```
- **Guardian.php**

  ```
  public function student()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
  }
  ```

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a place to write code for you. If you want to hire someone to write the code, well - hire one.

Comment: Hi there, I am just asking how to sort the results in the Polymorphic Relations. As you can see, I provided the query, and I just need some  answers on how to do the sorting process. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-sortby):

```php
$taxonomies = Taxonomy::with('entity.guardian')
    ->where('entity_type', 'Student')
    ->get();

// Solution #1: Sort results by student name.
$sortedTaxonomies = $taxonomies->sortBy('entity.name');
return $sortedTaxonomies->values();

// Solution #2: Sort results by student's guardian name.
$sortedTaxonomies = $taxonomies->sortBy('entity.guardian.name');
return $sortedTaxonomies->values();
```

Comment: Your code actually missing something for it to work. May I update your code, please?
But it actually answered my question. This is the solution I'm looking for. Thank you! :)

Comment: Good point about `values()`. If you return a JSON response, `->all()` is not necessary.